# static function with no prototype (AIX compiler allowed, gcc doesn't)

Tags: gcc, static, prototype, aix

I'm attempting to port a large set of modules from AIX to Linux.  Unfortunately, the AIX xlc compiler allowed you to define a static function and use it prior to the definition with no prototype.  Not good, but at least you get the proper static scope.  In any case, the code is there, and I can't get it to compile on Linux without explicitly adding a static prototype.

So, is there any way to inhibit the "static declaration follows non-static declaration" error in gcc (or make it a warning instead of a hard error), or do I have to edit each of these modules to add prototypes wherever they're missing?  As I understand it, this is a case where the standard behavior is undefined - so it's kind of nasty if gcc wouldn't allow you a way to relax its internal standard to allow for code that compiles elsewhere, no...?

Comment: Kindly attach a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

This has been a hard error in GCC since 2004. The only option to get this to compile is to downgrade to a really old version of GCC.  I verified that GCC 3.4.6 still compiles this, but GCC 4.0.3 does not.

Of course, depending on your target, getting GCC 3.4 to work might be close to impossible.

Comment: Thanks.  I was afraid of that.  I ported an earlier version of this stuff back in circa 2000, and didn't see this error.  But time marches on.  I can fix em as I encounter them.

Comment: While I have your attention, there's another similar issue I'm seeing that also wasn't a problem last time.  Prototypes for functions with a structure as a parameter now seem to have to be defined *after* the structure definition.  If not you get a nasty error message when calling the function that says the parameter doesn't match the prototype - and worse, it displays the prototype, which seems to match.  Moving the prototype to come after the structure definition fixes this.  But it wasn't a problem with gcc back in 2000...

Comment: In the old days, it may have dependent on the target, and whether it could pass structs in registers or not.

Comment: Here's another variant on the 'problem'.  I found a module that had for some reason included a local static version of a function that's in a library it uses - with a non-static prototype in an include file up top.   That should be pretty safe to do.  I.e., I want my own special version of a function just for this module (for debugging or some other purpose).  In any case, if you redefine the prototype to be static prior to ever calling it, gcc's just being overly persnickity to treat that as a hard error, IMO.